# Manga/manhwa in which the female lead and her husband die and are reincarnated in a book

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai, reincarnation

I read this this a few years ago and can't remember it. Details are fuzzy. The female lead and her husband die and are reincarnated in a book.

They were of nobility. When she is reborn, she is a sorceress. She ends up meeting her husband, but he has no memories of his past life.

He is nobility and has some type of magical sickness. He hires her to help him. She does, but wears a cloak to hide her face from him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  Do you remember where?

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[The Cure for Passion](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-cure-for-passion)***...?

> Asha the potion maker remembers everything about her tragic past life, including her former husband, Karligo. They were in a seemingly loveless marriage that constantly left Asha feeling lonely and unfulfilled because Karligo would never even look at her, let alone touch her. But in this life, Asha has met a drastically changed Karligo! Now that he's afflicted with uncontrollable desire and feverish lust, can Asha cure him before his fiery passion burns them both?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "The Cure for Passion."]

A blonde duchess named Rena spent five years in a loveless marriage with her black-haired husband, Karligo Edmund, before they were accused of being rebels and killed by knights sent by the Emperor.

Rena subsequently wakes up in the world of a novel she'd read as Asha Bliss, a potion maker with her own shop. Asha is summoned to the manor of Archduke Karligo Aetus, the male lead of the novel who's notorious for being a tyrant and a philanderer. When she meets him though, she immediately recognises him as her dead former husband, since they both look the same as they did in their previous lives. She's wearing a hooded cloak, however, and that, combined with dim lighting, is apparently enough to prevent him from recognising her.

Karligo wants Asha to make him a potion to supress his sexual desires, and she thinks to herself how uncomfortable it must be for him to be trapped in the body of a lustful playboy, when he was so sexually restrained in his previous life that they never actually consummated their marriage.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/the-cure-for-passion/info).